# this is the correct way to rename SMB file in java?

Tags: java, file, smb

I am writing code for rename smb file ,
is this a correct way to rename smb file in java?
if not suggest me code to rename smb file.

```
private static void renameSmbFile(String url, String folder, NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth) {
    try
    {
        
    
    directoryPath= new SmbFile(url+folder+"/");
    directoryPath.connect();
    List<SmbFile> smb = Arrays.asList(directoryPath.listFiles());

    for (SmbFile smbfile :smb)
    {
        String fileName = smbfile.getName();
        //String fileName = smbfile.getCanonicalPath();
        int index = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        fileName = fileName.substring(0,index)+".pdf";
        //new File(fileName).renameTo(new File(nameWithoutProtocol));
        SmbFile smbR =new SmbFile(fileName);
        smbfile.renameTo(smbR);
    }
    
    
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you mention the origin for the class SmbFile somewhere, so that we can lookup how that class is to be used.

Comment: What purpose does the `List` `smb` have? The `for` loop will work on an array in the same way as on a `List`.

Comment: What about the `auth` parameter? It is never used somewhere.

Comment: so this is the correct way or not??

Comment: Looks to be correct for JCifs